# What is the difference between hallmark and trademark?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The word 'trademarks' has been used in relation to characteristics of an agile business model and I do not think it is a reasonable usage of the word

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, the word "hall" was used to refer to what we would now call a "place". A hall was usually a specific workshop or sometimes even a city where hand-made items were crafted by artisans.

A "hallmark" was a stamp placed on clay bowl, silver fork, or other hand-made item in order to show where the clay bowl or silver fork was manufactured.

For example, if a wooden barrel was made in London, then you might stamp a symbol on the barrel to show that it was from London.

Likewise, hand-made crystal and glass drinking glasses bear hallmarks.

Overtime, the word "hallmark" has been used more and more metaphorically.

Today, a "hallmark" is a visual or auditory queue which makes it apparent which person or organization made a thing.

For example,

> "A **hallmark** of a child's writing is they connect separate sentences with the word 'and' instead of using periods or full-stops."

I think you are personally comfortable with "hallmark" being used in an almost-poetic sense. However, you want the word "trademark" to be used very literally.

It seems that you view a trade-mark as a legal thing; a visual symbol which you can pay the government for exclusive legal rights to use.

Well, like the word "hallmark," the word "trade-mark" is being used less and less literally these days. I don't see a problem with that.

> "A **trademark** of well-designed designed kitchen utensil is that they have a smooth surface. This allows for easier cleaning. The more creases, groves, and microscopic valleys that a kitchen utensil has on its surface, the more likely food particles are to be trapped and difficult to remove."

Answer (score 0):

Trademark is generally used to mean words or symbols that distinguish one source of goods from another. However, it also has a looser meaning of being the way someone habitually performs a task.

An example of that latter meaning, "The comedian ___ has a trademark of wearing a clown wig during his act." Unlike legal trademarks this form of use is generally not protectible (although the clown wig example *might* qualify under trade dress protections).

Hallmark has a niche meaning of being a purity stamp for precious metals but outside that small usage will almost always refer to a particular greeting card company instead.

Comment: Hallmark can be figuratively used to mean 'a typical characteristic or feature of a person or thing', e.g. Simplicity is a hallmark of this design. This explosion bears/has all the hallmarks of (= is likely to have been) a terrorist attack.